# Spring Integration and returning schema validation errors

Tags: spring, spring-integration, json-schema-validator

We are using Spring Integration to process a JSON payload passed into a RESTful endpoint. As part of this flow we are using a filter to validate the JSON:

```
.filter(schemaValidationFilter, s -> s
    .discardFlow(f -> f
        .handle(message -> {
            throw new SchemaValidationException(message);
        }))
)
```

This works great. However, if the validation fails we want to capture the parsing error and return that to the user so they can act on the error. Here is the overridden **accept** method in the SchemaValidationFilter class:

```
@Override
public boolean accept(Message<?> message) {
  Assert.notNull(message);
  Assert.isTrue(message.getHeaders().containsKey(TYPE_NAME));

  String historyType = (String)message.getHeaders().get(TYPE_NAME);
  JSONObject payload = (JSONObject) message.getPayload();
  String jsonString = payload.toJSONString();

  try {
      ProcessingReport report = schemaValidator.validate(historyType, payload);
      return report.isSuccess();
  } catch (IOException | ProcessingException e) {
      throw new MessagingException(message, e);
  }
```

}

What we have done is in the catch block we throw a MessageException which seems to solve the problem. However this seems to break what a filter should do (simply return a true or false).

Is there a best practice for passing the error details from the filter to the client? Is the filter the right solution for this use case?

Thanks for your help!
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you go correct way. Please, refer to the `XmlValidatingMessageSelector`, so your `JsonValidatingMessageSelector` should be similar and must follow the same design.

Since we have a `throwExceptionOnRejection` option we always can be sure that throwing Exception instead of just `true/false` is correct behavior.

What Gary says is good, too, but according to the existing logic in that `MessageSelector` impl we can go ahead with the same and continue to use `.filter()`, but, of course, already without `.discardFlow()`, because we won't send invalid message to the `discardChannel`.

When your `JsonValidatingMessageSelector` is ready, feel free to contribute it back to the [Framework](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT)!

Comment: Creating the `JsonValidatingMessageSelector` sounds like the right approach especially since `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` can be used as the pattern. Since we are doing consulting we will need to check with the company we are working for to see if we can contribute back to the framework. I will ask!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more correct to do the validation in a `<service-activator/>`...

```
public Message<?> validate(Message<?> message) {

    ...

    try {
        ProcessingReport report = schemaValidator.validate(historyType, payload);
        return message;
    } 
    catch (IOException | ProcessingException e) {
        throw new MessagingException(message, e);
    }
}
```

...since you're never really filtering.

Comment: You are right, we are not really filtering. Instead of rethrowing the exception in the catch block we would have returned a "false" instead. Since `XmlValidatingMessageSelector` seems to be a pattern we will use that for our needs. Thank you for your help!